# Multiprocessing Queue won't reset between program executions

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am getting some perplexing behaviour from Multiprocessing.Queue.

Each time I run this program the output alternates between `"a"` and `"[]"`. The standard Queue doesn't behave this way.

```
import multiprocessing


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.results = []

    def put(self, x):
        self.q.put(x)

    def pop(self):
        if not self.q.empty():
            self.results = self.q.get()


myObject = MyClass()
myObject.put("a")
myObject.pop()
print(myObject.results)
```

Comment: Whether multiprocessing.Queue or queue.Queue, `queue.empty()` is not a safe or reliable operation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm a little uncertain as to how to fix this. Is there teardown code I can call?

Comment: It is unlikely that this has anything to do with things not resetting between executions.

Comment: I tried adding the following lines to the end of the script. The problem persists. What do you think the problem could be? `myObject.q.close()`
`myObject.q.join_thread()`

Comment: Stop calling `empty`. Just call `get`.

Comment: My actual use case involves retrieving everything from the queue in one call, like this: `while not self.q.empty: self.results.append(self.q.get())`. This is why I included the superfluous check. Why does it break so badly when I call empty()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182136/discussion-between-glacecelery-and-user2357112).